# java ZonedDateTime parse error for milliseconds part

Tags: java, datetime, exception, zoneddatetime

```
ZonedDateTime zdt3 = ZonedDateTime.parse("1999-09-09 09:09:09.999", 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.xxx"));
```

Runtime error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text '1999-09-09 09:09:09.999' could not be parsed at index 20

How to fix my case?

Comment: `x` presents `zone-offset` (`offset-z`) and should be like `+0000` `-08` `-0830` `-08:30` `-083015` `-08:30:15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) of `ZonedDateTime`:

> A date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as
>   2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

`1999-09-09 09:09:09.999` does not hold any zone information, it could be a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
LocalDateTime zdt3 = LocalDateTime.parse("1999-09-09 09:09:09.999",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```